# MySQL Cluster Master Master Replication - broken Leg

Tags: replication, mysql-cluster, multi-master

I have two MySQL Clusters which normally operate with Master - Master Replication between two of their nodes.

Site 1 gets the majority of the write traffic, with Site 2 writing small amounts of isolated tables. The Auto Inc's are configured differently, so they can not clash.

[image: Cluster Diagram]

Site 1 App 1 -> Site 2 App 1 replication is working fine, and was started using the recommended method on [MySQL's website](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysql-cluster-replication-multi-master.html).

I had Site 2 App 1 replicating to Site 1 App 1 using the `SHOW MASTER STATUS` method, and starting the replication from that position.

Last week, Site 2 App 1 was restarted, and Site 1 -> Site 2 replication restarted fine. Site 2 App 1 -> Site 1 App 1 was attempted to restart using `SKIP ERRORS` to ignore the cluster log file break error (I can't remember the name).

This replication keeps breaking with:

> Error 'Can't write; duplicate key in table ''' on query. Default database: ''. Query: 'COMMIT'

I can't do the normal method (getting the epoch from `ndb_binlog_index`), because it doesn't return any files. Any time I try the `SHOW MASTER STATUS` method, it brings up the error above. I've even tried doing it via Site 2 App 2 -> Site 1 App 2, and it still fails.

Any ideas?